# LatLng constructor changing latitude value to -90.0

Tags: android, google-maps

For some reason the constructor for LatLng is changing the latitude value to -90.0 but the longitue value is fine.

```
    for (DealMarker m : markers.getMarkers()) {

        Log.d("map " , "pre - lat " + m.getmLatitude() + "  " + m.getmLongitude());

            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(m.getmLatitude(), m.getmLongitude());

            Log.d("map " , "post lat " + latlng.latitude + "  " + latlng.longitude);

        Marker deallocation = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(m.getTitle()).snippet(m.getSnippett()));
    }
```

This produces a log file like:
09-28 19:26:50.212: D/map(17784): pre - lat -121.6176785  39.1417939
09-28 19:26:50.212: D/map(17784): post lat -90.0  39.1417939

for each marker..  I am at a loss been working on this for hours. Thank you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just look at the documentation of the [LatLng constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html#LatLng%28double,%20double%29). It says:

> **public LatLng (double latitude, double longitude)**
>
> Constructs a LatLng with the given latitude and longitude, measured in degrees.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> **latitude** : The point's latitude. This will be clamped to between -90 degrees and +90 degrees inclusive.
>
> **longitude** :  The point's longitude. This will be normalized to be within -180 degrees inclusive and +180 degrees exclusive.

I think that should answer your query why latitude is clamped between -90 and 90.

Comment: DOH -- lat and long are reversed!  Thank you